# How to make a transparent window with Qt Quick 2.0

Tags: qt, window, transparent, qt5, qtquick2

I've already know how to make a transparent window with Qt Quick 1.0.But I started to use Qt 5.0 and Qt Quick 2.0 recently and didn't know how to do with it.

setAttribute
setWindowFlags
setStyleSheet

The functions above are removed from the QtQuick2ApplicationViewer(QQuickView).
So I wonder whether I can make a transparent window with Qt Quick 2 or not
(is it because that it's based on OpenGL?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Qt5 code:

```
QSurfaceFormat surfaceFormat;
surfaceFormat.setAlphaBufferSize(8);
viewer.setFormat(surfaceFormat);
viewer.setClearBeforeRendering(true);
viewer.setColor(QColor(Qt::transparent));
```

Comment: It works well! Thanks.
In addition,I used 'viewer.setFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);'to hide the caption bar.
But when I clicked the transparent area,it still responded to the event.How to deal with it?

Comment: @XuHongxu see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4930925/721710 for a Windows solution...

Comment: @andrewrjones - please check again, this solution worked for me on OSX 10.9.1, Qt 5.1.1. This should be marked as the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Look here for a possible solution:</s>

http://code.google.com/p/quickwidget/

But, with `Qt 5.3`, it is possible to use the built-in `QQuickWidget` class.

Comment: Sorry,I found nothing in this website.

Comment: @XuHongxu: check out or view the source code! I even wrote an example.

Comment: Thanks i found it.It's useful!

Comment: But when I clicked the transparent area,it still responded to the event(I can't click other window under its transparent area).How to deal with it?

Comment: set a mask (i.e. call setMask()), otherwise Qt doesn't know which clicks to pass through.