# Qml window with transparent mask

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I write some app and need to create window with transparency mask.
How I can create QtQuick 2.0 top level window with masked transparency?

Comment: http://www.lothlorien.com/kf6gpe/?p=204

Comment: @khajvah Nope, that QtQuick 1.0

Comment: My bad, it really doesn't work with qtquick 2.0

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009549/how-to-make-a-transparent-window-with-qt-quick-2-0)

Comment: @khajvah doesn`t work for me =(

Comment: Dcom: does not work is a poor definition of the problem. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28214
For now `quickwidget` don`t work.
Change SurfaceFormat does not work too.

Comment: I do not think there is any other way to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mask, you can use setMask function of QWindow, it's work for QQuickView. But you need to launch QML UI with QQuickView and not with qmlscene application (cf http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qwindow.html#setMask)

Comment: How I should set a mask as Image with Alpha channel?

Comment: Yes, using QPixmap::mask() : view.setMask(QPixmap(":/images/mask.png").mask());

Comment: I`m sorry, but what about semi transparency? I apply same mask for window and that what I see : http://gyazo.com/11ad63fc89baed0c62691ef3fe5d657e

Comment: Mask use binary value, then you can't set real value for alpha. Use opacity property (for unique alpha value in item) ou Image (I think jpeg format is not well supported for alpha channel, use png. or inverse).

Comment: I use png image with alpha for mask and background.
What exactly I need to do ?

Comment: You can use mask with QQuickView (for no rectangular shaping) and Image as main item (with you png) for transparent. Maybe it's better to generate black and white image from your png for the mask.

Comment: Same result with QQUickView and Image as main obj http://gyazo.com/48b9b1d327ee90208d5037d4058fbe50