# How can I make custom frame border in QML

Tags: qt, windows-10, qml, qt6, windows-11

I want to make cross-platform app in Qt Quick - QML. 
Something like this:

[image]

But don't know - how to make this, because of rounded corners in Win 11.
App will starts on both Windows (10 and 11)
And frame icons (hide, close, fullscreen) and corners should me standart, but "S" logo - not.

Can you help me with advice how to code this or what do you see as a possible solution?
Thanks!

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18764687/qml-window-with-transparent-mask can be of help

Comment: @Amfasis - Thanks! But problem not in transparanty. Probem is that I need standart frame with logo with transparenty on it

Comment: I think you will have to roll your own frame completely. One thing worth trying is using negative margins with this transparency mask, so that you can have the logo "stick out" from the standard frame

Comment: @Amfasis "negative margins" - what is it?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG "standard frame"? What exactly do you mean by "standard frame"? AFAIK, if you need a custom frame window with native functionality, you must reimplement those features yourself on the Cpp side. Other UI designs could be made using QML `Shapes`, `SVG`, or `ShaderEffect`. Also, have a look at [this](https://github.com/wangwenx190/framelesshelper).

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG with negative margins I mean that you create a mask which is bigger than the frame itself (i.e. `anchors.fill: parent; anchors.topMargin: -10`)

Comment: https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. We need to make frameless borber by flag:

   flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
2. We need to separate title on 2 pieces (left, with Logo, and rigth, with buttons). Rigth side can be made by WinApi, or QML.
3. Rigth side can be made only by custom QQuickPaintedItem:

Example here: https://gist.github.com/oKcerG/b9527a638b01523c3c9c06647d373338